# Is biotin a hapten? If so, how does it work as a hapten in the human body?

Tags: immunology, nutrition

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapten

Hapten's aren't synonymous with allergens. It is defined as a foreign molecule that can bind to an antibody but does not evoke an immune response unless combined with a carrier protein.